# Как понять, почему ноутбук на Linux не видит наушники?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluetooth-le

На ноутбуке (Linux) в списке найденных bluetooth-устройств вижу много чужих устройств, но не вижу свои наушники. (Ни ноутбук, ни наушники ни с чем не сопряжены в это время).
При этом есть телефон, который удавалось успешно сопрячь как с наушниками, так и с ноутбуком.
Вот такую информацию о наушниках получил с телефоноа:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такую информацию о ноуте получил с телефона
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался сделать что-то такое:

```
[dvr@think ~]$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
[bluetooth]# devices
Device 52:4B:A[bluetooth]# pair 71:47:23:FA:AD:9E
Device 71:47:23:FA:AD:9E not available
[bluetooth]# trust 71:47:23:FA:AD:9E
Device 71:47:23:FA:AD:9E not available
[bluetooth]# connect 71:47:23:FA:AD:9E
Device 71:47:23:FA:AD:9E not available
[bluetooth]# 
D:07:30:22 52-4B-AD-07-30-22
Device 6A:BF:8A:25:D6:27 6A-BF-8A-25-D6-27
Device 9C:05:67:EC:92:3D HONOR Earbuds 2 Lite
Device FF:6B:24:A0:65:43 Mi Smart Band 4
Device 88:F8:72:DA:66:28 HATIKO3
[bluetooth]# scan on
[bluetooth]# agent on
[bluetooth]# pair 71:47:23:FA:AD:9E
Device 71:47:23:FA:AD:9E not available
[bluetooth]# trust 71:47:23:FA:AD:9E
Device 71:47:23:FA:AD:9E not available
[bluetooth]# connect 71:47:23:FA:AD:9E
Device 71:47:23:FA:AD:9E not available
[bluetooth]#
```

Comment: наушники в режим сопряжения и временно выключи блютус на телефоне

Comment: может ноут не умеет 5,0, а наушники не умеют 3,0